# Finding out much time is required for TCP to reach desired sequence

Tags: tcp, numbers, sequence

Assume a TCP is sending at 100Mbps. The sequence number starts with 329,114,852. how long will it take in seconds before the sequence number reaches 100,000,000

I don't have the answer for this so i am not sure if my working is correct. (329,144,852-100,000,000)/100,000,000 =2.29 seconds

Comment: No, there is a wraparound. The sequence number has to go to 100,000,000 via zero. So you need 2^32+100,000,000-329,144,852 bytes to be transmitted.

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand why do i have to get 2 to the power of 32 and add it with 100,000,000